# Show custom message when filtering from multiple div element returns no result in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

With `javascript` filtering I filter book names from the available `div` elements. But I also have another `div` containing a custom message for inputs that are not available.

It works fine for some of the keywords but doesn't work in an expected way if, for example, the input is `har`. Then it shows both the book result and not found the custom message.

Can you please explain to me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

```js
const searchBar = document.forms['search-books'].querySelector('input');
searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    const term = e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase();
    const books = document.getElementsByTagName('h5');
    Array.from(books).forEach(function(book) {
        var notAvailable = document.getElementById('notAvailable');
        const title = book.textContent;
        if (title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1) {
            book.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'flex';
            notAvailable.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            book.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
            notAvailable.style.display = 'block';
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form id="search-books">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Search a book ... ">
</form>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row list-single">
      <div class="col-2"><img src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1447303603s/2767052.jpg"/></div>
      <div class="col-10">
         <h5> The Hunger Games</h5>
         <a href="The-Hunger-Games.html">Learn</a> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="row list-single">
      <div class="col-2"><img src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1507396732s/2.jpg"/></div>
      <div class="col-10">
         <h5>Harry Potter</h5>
         <a href="Harry-Potter.html">Learn</a> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row list-single" id="notAvailable" style="display: none;">
      <div class="col-12">
         <h5>Sorry, the book has not been added yet</h5>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are toggling the style of `#notAvailable` in each iteration of array. Meaning that it's final display value will depend only on last element of array.

Here's a working version:

```js
const searchBar = document.forms['search-books'].querySelector('input');
searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    const term = e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase();
    const books = document.getElementsByTagName('h5');
    var notAvailable = document.getElementById('notAvailable');
    
    var hasResults = false;
    Array.from(books).forEach(function (book) {
        const title = book.textContent;
        if (title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1) {
            book.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'flex';
            hasResults = true;
        } else {
            book.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
    notAvailable.style.display = hasResults ? 'none' : 'block'; 
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form id="search-books">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Search a book ... ">
</form>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row list-single">
      <div class="col-2"><img src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1447303603s/2767052.jpg"/></div>
      <div class="col-10">
         <h5> The Hunger Games</h5>
         <a href="The-Hunger-Games.html">Learn</a> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="row list-single">
      <div class="col-2"><img src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1507396732s/2.jpg"/></div>
      <div class="col-10">
         <h5>Harry Potter</h5>
         <a href="Harry-Potter.html">Learn</a> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row list-single" id="notAvailable" style="display: none;">
      <div class="col-12">
         <h5>Sorry, the book has not been added yet</h5>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Cheers. :)

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. Very much appreciate the explanation. Cheers.  :)

Comment: No problem really, glad I could help. If this answer helped you, please mark it as correct. :)